# Context menu and Filters issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, contextmenu

I am trying to have both context menu as well as filter in my page but after I filter and reload the page I get this exception

DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.

```
        <p:dataTable
        id="wtmInbox"
        rendered="#{flowDashboardManagedBean.renderOnLoadForWtm}"
        value="#{flowDashboardManagedBean.worktimematrixList}"
        var="wtms"
        stickyHeader="false"
        tableStyleClass="IEListTable"
        widgetVar="wtmInboxWidVar"
        scrollable="true"
        scrollHeight="700"
        editable="true" rowKey="#{wtms.worktimematrix.workTimeMatrixId}" selection="#{flowDashboardManagedBean.selectedWorktimematrix}" selectionMode="single">

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{flowDashboardManagedBean.onRowEdit}" update="wtmInbox"/>
        <p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{flowDashboardManagedBean.onRowSelect}" ></p:ajax>
```

filter :

```
   <p:column headerText="#{bundle.status}"
                  sortBy="#{wtms.worktimematrix.workTimeMatrixStatus.name}"
                  filterBy="#{wtms.worktimematrix.workTimeMatrixStatus.name}"
                  filterMatchMode="exact"
                  style="text-align:right;"
                  priority="1"
                  width="10%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{wtms.worktimematrix.workTimeMatrixStatus}" converter="workTimeMatrixStatusConverter"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{wtms.worktimematrix.workTimeMatrixStatus}" converter="workTimeMatrixStatusConverter">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.select}" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{flowDashboardManagedBean.workTimeMatrixStatuses}" var="worktimematrixStatus" itemValue="#{worktimematrixStatus}" itemLabel="#{worktimematrixStatus.name}"></f:selectItems>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>

             <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('wtmInboxWidVar').filter()" id="flowModelTypeFilter">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.status}" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{flowDashboardManagedBean.workTimeMatrixStatusNames}" var="status" itemValue="#{status}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:column>
```

Comment: The error seems very clear to me...

Comment: You does not add the controller source, but I'm sure : your data model is not an ascendant of `SelectableDataModel`. Change its type to the expected one named in the error message.

Comment: The real issue here is I have removed the selection, now I apply filters i and when I reload the page I get 2 rows, when I re-render the datatable I get same 2 rows just that it is empty. ( hence I am getting the error when selection is there) . P.S : it is of type data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the Problem, The entity behind the table did not implement serializable. After I added that filters worked then when I added in the context menu it also worked.